# What is the most credible picture of Plato's Academy in Plato's time?

Tags: aristotle, plato, ancient-philosophy

I assume there actually was [an Academy set up by Plato](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_Academy) and not taken over by him and made famous.

In the paintings I've seen of it - admittedly done in the Renaissance -, it looks rather grand, like the Acropolis. I imagine this is far from the actual truth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glucker, *Antiochus and the Late Academy*:

> To us ... the word 'Academy' has come to mean an institution of learning, a learned society, or at least a place of theoretical ('academic') education. In ancient Athens, the Academy was first and foremost a public park dominated by its gymnasium, and the connection between it and Plato's school was only one of the numerous historical reminiscences in an area rich in history.

<sup>[*Source and otherwise related stuff*](http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/~history/Societies/Plato.html)</sup>

> The fresco *The School of Athens* by Raphael represents the modern idea of an academy and he has placed Plato and Aristotle into such a setting, but the reality of Plato's Academy must have been totally different.

<sup>*Same source*</sup>

Comment: ah, now the expression *groves of academia* makes sense!